# Who is behind monero and how does is compare to other major crypto currencies?

Tags: governance

Who is leading Monero? What are the process in place to avoid an hostile entity to take control of the network/the development/the security of the system? How resilience is achieved?

How does it compare to Bitcoin or Ethereum (for the latter, it is at least know that a company is behind it, with clear profitability goal and state(s) specific state laws and requests to comply with  - which in light of recent Yahoo events is at least bothering regarding privacy and back doors).

Comment: I really think this question would be much better without the accusations towards Ethereum. That is hardly useful and does not reflect well on Monero itself.

Comment: Agree that the Ethereum accusations don't belong in the question.

Comment: Edited to remove the accusations toward Ethereum and try to explain what is bothering with a company owning a currency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monero is open source, I don't think one can talk about a 'leader' of monero, though Riccardo Spagni (nick: fluffypony) might be considered, though I'm quite sure he wouldn't introduce himself as that, he is one of the main devs and also the 'public' spokesperson for monero. Also see this for a list of the core team members: https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people
I don't think (don't know) any processes to 'avoid' a hostile take over,however, if the community would be convinced that such thing had taken place the could always fork monero away from the current devteam, because monero is open source, that's not difficult to achieve...

Bitcoin used to be the same way I think, with off course as most important person Satoshi Nakamoto, but also lots of freelance contributors/developers, now bitcoin seams to much more corporate (blockstream: https://blockstream.com/) with a hierarchical structure and paid developers. Ethereum on the other hand has always been a corporation with an ICO (initial coin offering), a CEO (Vitalik Butterin) and paid developers... Whether it's a ponzi or not, I leave in the middle...

for more information about the history of monero, one could start by looking over here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3f2fpd/the_strange_birth_history_of_monero_part_i_wtf_is/