# What is novault and what is its connection to Monero?

Tags: security, development, encryption, python

What is the primary purpose of [novault](https://github.com/novault/novault/releases/tag/0.201)? Is it safe to use? Is the tool meant to be used just Monero or does it had wider applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its [GitHub description](https://github.com/novault/novault#id11):

> novault is a command-line utility and Python module for generating passwords and cryptocurrency wallets from a combination of a description and a master password. The description and master password are hashed, generating a pseudo-random seed which is then formatted as a password or wallet keys/address.

There is no official connection between Novault and Monero but the first two currencies supported are Bitcoin and Monero. The author accepts donations in Monero and stated in the tools [r/monero announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5awpa2/new_tool_novault_combines_monero_brain_wallets/):

> My main motivation to develop novault started with my use of Monero, but since this is not a purely-Monero tool I opened a subreddit at /r/novault. You are welcome to comment to this post or open new ones in /r/novault.

Since this tool is not an official Monero project a review of its safety is outside of the scope of this Stack Exchange. Having said that at least one Monero [core developer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/who-is-behind-monero-and-how-does-is-compare-to-other-major-crypto-currencies), Riccardo Spagni has [expressed interest](https://twitter.com/fluffyponyza/status/794428322105217028) in it. Users can review the [source code](https://github.com/novault/novault/releases/tag/0.201) and make their own conclusion.